# Collapse Rows into a Single Field via Netezza Query

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm working in a table that has variables stored in a long/tall format. I need to convert it into a wide format for use in a project. Basically I need to aggregate a text field, or collapse by name. Sample data below, and the table I'm working with has ~400k rows:

```
IID     NAME  LANGUAGE  TID
  1  William   English   76
  1  William    French   82
  1  William   Spanish   12
  1  William    German   63
  2   George    German   39
  2   George    French   53
  3     Dave   English   29
```

What I need to get to is a single row for each Individual ID/Name, with a field that lists all languages spoken by that individual. I don't need to account for the Transaction ID.

```
IID     NAME                      LANGUAGES
  1  William  English_French_German_Spanish
  2   George                  French_German
  3     Dave                        English
```

My database is Netezza, which is a derivative of PostgreSQL. I've created a SQL fiddle that uses PostgreSQL. I've managed to capture two of the languages, but my query misses more than 2 and shows double when there's only 1. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55706/1

```
SELECT T1.IID, T1.NAME,
    MIN(T1.LANGUAGE) || '_' || MAX(T1.LANGUAGE) AS LANGUAGES

FROM Table1 AS T1

GROUP BY T1.IID, T1.NAME

ORDER BY T1.IID
;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came across the answer while searching for documentation on the command in [Dhaval's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5814422/dhaval-shah) answer. There's a thread on IBM's DeveloperWorks community that addresses this exact question, [Group Concat in Netezza](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e1540f81-869c-4cd9-b521-55f00d546388). The solution that worked for me is within the [5th response](https://web.archive.org/web/20191226174926/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e1540f81-869c-4cd9-b521-55f00d546388), written by [Diwakar Nahata](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/profiles/html/profileView.do?userid=270006M9UG#&tabinst=Updates). Here's the code that solved it for me:

```
SELECT A.IID, A.NAME,
    RTRIM(MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 1 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END)||','|| 
        MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 2 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END)||','||
        MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 3 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END)||','||
        MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 4 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END)||','||
        MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 5 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END)||','||
        MAX(CASE RNO WHEN 6 THEN A.LANGUAGE ELSE '' END),',') AS LANGUAGES
FROM (SELECT
        IID,
        NAME,
        LANGUAGE,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (PARTITION BY IID, NAME ORDER BY LANGUAGE) AS RNO
    FROM Table1 ) AS A
GROUP BY A.IID, A.NAME
;
```

Here's a link to the solved [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55706/9). This fiddle is set to PostgreSQL, but this query also works perfectly for me within Netezza.

Answer (score 3):

Try using group_concat
Your query will be like:

```
SELECT T1.IID, T1.NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(T1.LANGUAGE,'_') AS LANGUAGES
FROM Table1 AS T1
GROUP BY T1.IID, T1.NAME
ORDER BY T1.IID;
```

A blog [link](http://dwgeek.com/netezza-group_concat-alternative-working-example.html/) that will help you understand this analytic function better

Hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get the error `ERROR AGG: PERMISSION DENIED`. It did lead me to a few spots that I hadn't come across before though, so your answer did help. Thanks for taking the time.